# Quantum Boltzmann Machine and Gibbs state

Tags: quantum-algorithms, machine-learning, quantum-enhanced-machine-learning

I was looking into Quantum Boltzmann Machine and ran into Gibbs State as a part of training.
Since new to this field, it would be good to have good intuitions why Gibbs state is related.  Is Gibbs state simple the same as the ground state in this context?

Any pointer would be highly appreciated

Comment: Some clarification would help. Can you add (in the post itself, not in the comments) links to the sources you are reading? What's your understanding of "Gibbs state" here? Where did you see the term?

Comment: @glS  Thank you for the question.    here is  https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.06004.pdf   and  I found this  https://vrs.amsi.org.au/wp-content/uploads/sites/78/2021/01/naghdi_saleh_vrs-report.pdf